# Relation between health and coffee

Tags: coffee

I've been drinking a cup of coffee every morning for about 3 continuous years.

Does this daily activity have a negative effect on my health?

Comment: It would be great if you've made additional research before posting such question, just for posterity.

Comment: Requests for personal medical advice are off topic here, so I edited your question to comply.