# What are the health benefits of coffee?

Tags: benefits, healthy-cooking, coffee

I'm not a coffee fan, but  I would like to know what are the health benefits of the coffee ?
Some people say good for body fitness etc,

Like to get an idea about coffee.

Comment: Although there is no answer, this is the same question as https://health.stackexchange.com/q/13894

Comment: @Chris - Thanks, I dont like to drink coffee, but I so people love to drink so like to know about coffee . online and paper articles have specific people knowledge here can exchange the knowledge.